# Can you use 持つ to mean 'to wait'?

Tags: translation, meaning, verbs

パーティーに何か持って行きましょうか。

My translation – “Do you want to hold/wait on going to the party?”

Is this translation correct basically? I wasn’t sure if ‘to hold’ could be used in the same sense as ‘to wait’ in Japanese as is the case in English as when I look up 持つ in my dictionary it doesn’t give a possible meaning of ‘to wait’.

Comment: Your sentence is much like: Would you like to put this reservation **on hold** until next Wednesday? It's the concept of waiting or biding time. As opposed to actually/physically holding something. Maybe 待つ is used for that colloquialism/idiom as well.

Comment: By the way, 侍 (samurai)、待つ (matsu)、持つ (motsu)、時 (toki)，寺 (tera) are several characters that have the same 寺 part.

Comment: Have you checked [持]{も}っていく in your dictionary? http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E3%82%92%E6%8C%81%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%81%8F

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, [持]{も}つ cannot mean 'to wait', your translation is incorrect. Are you confusing it with [待]{ま}つ?

> パーティーに何か[持]{も}って行きましょうか。
>   "Shall we go ahead and bring something along to the party?"

Comment: I wasn't actually (though I do sometimes mix the two up in my head in terms of reading), I just didn't know how else to translate the sentence. I'd overlooked 何か however which I've just looked up means 'something' so now the sentence makes sense as you translated it.